# how to implement AdBannerview and ADBannerview delegate

Tags: iphone, cocoa, iad

I am having trouble implementing ADBannerView and its delegate protocol.

I implemented the following code in my view class (also made the view conform to the ADBannerViewDelegate protocol):

```
//add iAds
ADBannerView *adView = [[ADBannerView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(0, 318, 320, 50)];
adView.requiredContentSizeIdentifiers = [NSSet setWithObjects: ADBannerContentSizeIdentifierPortrait, ADBannerContentSizeIdentifierLandscape, nil];
adView.delegate = self; 
//adView.delegate = ADBannerViewDelegate;
[self.view addSubview: adView];
```

then I created a class for the ADBannerViewDelegate, with the following .m

```
//
//  ADBannerViewDelegate.m
//

#import "ADBannerViewDelegate.h"

@implementation ADBannerViewDelegate

- (void)bannerView:(ADBannerView *)banner didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(NSError *)error{
    NSLog(@"bannerview did not receive any banner due to %@", error);}

- (void)bannerViewActionDidFinish:(ADBannerView *)banner{NSLog(@"bannerview was selected");}

- (BOOL)bannerViewActionShouldBegin:(ADBannerView *)banner willLeaveApplication:(BOOL)willLeave{return willLeave;}

- (void)bannerViewDidLoadAd:(ADBannerView *)banner {NSLog(@"banner was loaded");}

@end
```

the banners are eventually presented but the console keep throwing the following type of errors:

```
2011-02-27 15:00:54.108 app[31639:207] ADBannerView: Unhandled error (no delegate or delegate does not implement didFailToReceiveAdWithError:): Error Domain=ADErrorDomain Code=5 "The operation couldn’t be completed. Banner view is visible but does not have content" UserInfo=0x6356a40 {ADInternalErrorCode=5, NSLocalizedFailureReason=Banner view is visible but does not have content}
```

and the delegate functions are not doing anything , so no NSLog at all. Obviously not catching the errors.

I am stumped. I guess I am missing something in the linkage of the Adbanner view calls in the view and the delegate. Not sure how to do it or what is wrong.

Any help? Thanks in advance.

Jason

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The reason why is you told the **AdBannerView** that you are its delegate but you never put it in your implementation file. Your implementation file should look like this (notice the line with `@implmentation`):

```
//
//  ADBannerViewDelegate.m
//

#import "ADBannerViewDelegate.h"

@implementation ADBannerViewDelegate<ADBannerViewDelegate>

- (void)bannerView:(ADBannerView *)banner didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(NSError *)error{
    NSLog(@"bannerview did not receive any banner due to %@", error);}

- (void)bannerViewActionDidFinish:(ADBannerView *)banner{NSLog(@"bannerview was selected");}

- (BOOL)bannerViewActionShouldBegin:(ADBannerView *)banner willLeaveApplication:(BOOL)willLeave{return willLeave;}

- (void)bannerViewDidLoadAd:(ADBannerView *)banner {NSLog(@"banner was loaded");}

@end
```

And also you shouldn't name your class **ADBannerViewDelegate**. Your class should be a delegate (respond to it) to **ADBannerView** but not be named after it.

Comment: It should be noted for method: bannerViewActionShouldBegin. The logic can be custom, but usually better to return YES. There are many ads served within the app (so willLeave will often be NO), but returning based off this value will prevent the ad from being fully served (when NO) and therefore decrease earnable revenue as per the AdBannerViewDelegate Protocol Reference (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Reference/ADBannerViewDelegate_Ref/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/ADBannerViewDelegate/bannerViewActionShouldBegin:willLeaveApplication:).

Comment: I am little confused, isn't Interface is which is need to conform to protocol not Implementation. I was trying this in test project when I wrote ADViewBannerDelete in Implementation, xcode threw this error.  @implementation declaration can not be protocol qualified

Answer (score 4):

i successfully integrated iAds in my app using this tutorial:
http://www.raywenderlich.com/1371/how-to-integrate-iad-into-your-iphone-app
might help you too.

Answer (score 2):

You don't try to implement a class named `ADBannerViewDelegate`, you put those methods in the implementation for your view class.

(If you actually named your view class "ADBannerViewDelegate", don't. It's confusing.)

Comment: thx. What I was trying to do is to create a generic class that acted as a delegate with all the functions. The reason is that I have a bunch of different views which call the Adbanner in the way I shows and didn't want litter all the views controller with the same code.

Comment: Then you shouldn't be assigning `adView.delegate = self;`, you should create an instance of your generic class and assign that as the delegate. Your view doesn't need to confrom to the `AdBannerViewDelegate` protocol in that case.

Answer (score 1):

For me it was the target and the device, I ran it on the 4.3 simulator and my ipad 2 but the app was for iphone 5.1, when I changed the target all went swimmingly

Comment: +1 Running iphone app in ipad simulator I got didFailToReceiveAdWithError immediately on setting the ADBannerView delegate, and never another delegate call.  Running it on the iphone simulator (or changing the app target to universal) the delegate only got called after adding ADBannerView as a subview, and delegate calls every 30 secs after that.

Answer (score 1):

you can Use this link its very helpful

http://codewithchris.com/iad-tutorial/