# iAds: bannerViewDidLoadAd no longer called after first didFailToReceiveAdWithError

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, iad

I'm testing iAds in XCode 4.

Everything works fine, until the first time a `bannerView:didFailToReceiveAdWithError:` is received, which I react to by sliding the banner off the screen.

```
//move the ad back off the screen if an error occurs
- (void)bannerView:(ADBannerView *)banner didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(NSError *)error {
    if (self.bannerIsInScreenBounds)
    {
        [UIView beginAnimations:@"animateAdBannerOff" context:NULL];
        // move the banner view off the screen.
        banner.frame = CGRectOffset(banner.frame, 320, 0);
        [UIView commitAnimations];
    }
}
```

After that, no more `bannerViewDidLoadAd:` messages are sent to the ADBannerViewDelegate. I'm logging that method right at the top, it's not being called any more.

I'm not releasing the banner or anything, and the ADBannerViewDelegate class is still there and doing other stuff.

What could be wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: What's the error you receive?

Comment: How do you know `bannerViewDidLoadAd:` is not being called? Can you add the method?

Comment: @deanWombourne - I don't receive any errors apart from the idFailToReceiveAdWithError: itself, which is normal ("the iAd Network occasionally returns errors to test your error handling code.". Anyway, it's "bannerView:idFailToReceiveAdWithError: Error Domain=ADErrorDomain Code=3 "The operation couldn’t be completed. Ad inventory unavailable" UserInfo=0x6ac22a0 {ADInternalErrorCode=3, NSLocalizedFailureReason=Ad inventory unavailable}"

Comment: @Deepak - I NSLogged bannerViewDidLoadAd: at the top of the method. The log is written fine (and the ad slides in if off the screen & works) until after I first get a bannerView:idFailToReceiveAdWithError:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, not an ideal solution but here's what I ended up doing.

Whenever I get a didFailToReceiveAdWithError, I wait 10 seconds (to avoid spamming with failures) then recreate the banner.

```
-(void)replaceAdView {
    UIView *adViewSuperview = [adView superview];
    [adView removeFromSuperview];
    [adView release];
    //starting off the screen again
    adView = [[NSClassFromString(@"ADBannerView") alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(320, 382, 320, 50)];
    adView.delegate = self;
    if (adViewSuperview) {
        [adViewSuperview addSubview:adView];
    }
    self.bannerIsInScreenBounds = NO;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you expect it load adverts after an error has happened - I think this is the correct behavior.

Looking at the comments it show that the error is "The operation couldn’t be completed. Ad inventory unavailable".

How do you expect it to give you adverts if it can't find any adverts to give ;)

Comment: Apple says "Even after an error is sent to your delegate, the banner view continues to try to download new advertisements. Thus, implementing both of these delegate methods allows your application to display the banner only when advertisements are loaded." See http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/iAd_Guide/WorkingwithBannerViews/WorkingwithBannerViews.html

Comment: That doesn't mean that after an error it will then definitely succeed in getting adverts to display - there is no guarantee that `bannerViewDidLoadAd:` will be called again, it just _might_ be called ;)

Comment: anyway, I'd try @Mike Howard's answer and see if that helps!

Answer (score 0):

As my comment at [how to implement AdBannerview and ADBannerview delegate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5135622/how-to-implement-adbannerview-and-adbannerview-delegate), running iphone app in ipad simulator I got `didFailToReceiveAdWithError` immediately on setting the ADBannerView delegate, and never another delegate call.  Running it on the iphone simulator (or changing the app target to universal) the delegate only got called after adding ADBannerView as a subview, and then delegate calls every 30 secs after that.